# Как создать вертикальную линию с временными отметками и кружочками в HTML, CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Пример желаемого результата]

Также нужно, чтобы верстка оставалась адаптивной и не ломалась (не смещалась/накладывалась на другие элементы страницы) на разных разрешениях экранах. Спасибо!

Comment: Приведите в вопросе ваши попытки решения, а также что вызвало у вас трудности.

Comment: ul ol списки думаю сгодятся, недостающие данные псевдоэлементами выводить(с подкладыванием `border-left` под маркеры). `так же нужно...` ааа... т.е. готовый код хотите) и скок платите? :3 p.s. ru.so не решебник, *тут вам могут и хотят помочь, но не выполнить задание вместо вас*